# Can't delete schema if migration needed in Realm

Tags: swift, realm, realm-migration

I have updated the Realm object in swift. I simply want to delete the schema and create a new one in case the app has the older version.

To achieve this I am using the following code:

```
   lazy var realm = try! Realm(configuration:Realm.Configuration(deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded: true))
```

But it results in `SchemaMismatchException` at this particular line.

I have also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38194786/848377) and code sample of [this](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3577). But I get same error at the line of declaration of Realm object.

Can anybody give the working code of this?

Comment: bdash is correct!
I just tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43817264/2296630) sampled and worked right!

Answer (score 0):

`SchemaMismatchException` is an exception that Realm throws internally. If `deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded` is true the exception is caught and the Realm is removed. If it is set to false, the exception is translated into an `NSError`. Seeing the exception be thrown in your case is expected.